# Change line chart to stacked line chart ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a quite basic question but I could not find any help.

I am plotting a "normal" line chart with five lines using ggplot. My df consists of one Year column and 5 value columns:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Year)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = y1, colour = "y1")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = y2, colour = "y2")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = y3, colour = "y3")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = y4, colour = "y4")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = y5, colour = "y5"))
```

I want to change it to a **stacked** line chart with filled areas between the lines. Is it possible without changing the command above too much?

Thank you!

Comment: BTW - have a look at [Stacked area chart vs. Line chart – The great debate](https://www.vizwiz.com/2012/10/stacked-area-chart-vs-line-chart-great.html)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean by "without changing the code too much". `ggplot2` is build on the principle of tidy data. Therefore life a.k.a. plotting with `ggplot2` becomes much easier if you convert your data to "tidy data" which in your case means converting your data to long format using e.g. `tidyr::pivot_longer`. This way you can make your plot in just two lines.

To get stacked areas switch to `geom_area`, map on the `fill` aes instead of `color` and set `position="stack"`.

Using some random example data try this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(42)

df <- data.frame(
  Year = 2000:2020,
  y1 = runif(21),
  y2 = runif(21),
  y3 = runif(21),
  y4 = runif(21),
  y5 = runif(21)
)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Year) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = value, fill = name)) +
  geom_area(position = "stack")
```

[image]